# Benchmarking in Ruby

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

I have been doing some benchmarking in Ruby and have the following results:

```
                           user     system      total        real
part1                  0.156000   0.000000   0.156000 (  0.158009)
                           user     system      total        real
part2                  0.015000   0.000000   0.015000 (  0.162010)
```

Commonly, as in part1, the total and real times are nearly the same. However this is not true in part 2.

1. What is the meaning of the total and real divergence in part2?
2. Does the divergence raise any concerns?
3. What run is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user/system are cpu times, measured by the kernel. which have scheduled your
process.
real time is the time of calculation.

So real time bigger than user+system mean :

- io or sleep in code tested
- there a other process/daemon which consumes CPU

Answer (score 0):

The results are organized in columns and are in this order; user CPU time, system CPU time, the sum of the user and system CPU times, and the elapsed real time. The units of them all are seconds. So in real time, `part1` was faster than `part2`.

Comment: In part2, if the user and systems total 0.015 but the total elapsed time is 0.162, where is/what caused the 0.147s delta?